# How to check if a specific Azure ARM Resource exists or not and if not exists create it with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to check if a specific gallery image version exists or not, if not exists create the image version.

```
Write-Host "Checking the image version already exists or not..................."
$VersionReqName=(Get-AzGalleryImageVersion -ResourceGroupName $rgname -GalleryName $galName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $imageDefinitionName -GalleryImageVersionName $versionName).Name

if($VersionReqName -eq $versionName)
{
    Write-Host "The image version which has been requested in this pipeline task already exists, no action is taken, goodbye!!!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else 
{

    Write-Host "Creating and replicating the new image, it may take hours depending on the size of the image and network speed"
    $ImageVersion=New-AzGalleryImageVersion -ResourceGroupName $rgname -GalleryName $galName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $imageDefinitionName -GalleryImageVersionName $versionName -Location $location -Source $sourceImageId -PublishingProfileEndOfLifeDate $endOfLifeDate -TargetRegion $targetRegions
    ############################## Publish new Image Gallery ####################### 
    Write-Host "The Gallery Image Version is ready please find below" -ForegroundColor "Green"
    $ImageVersion
}
```

However, I am getting the below error.

```
Checking the image version already exists or not...................
##[error]The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/WVDImageGallery3/images/WVDBaseImageDefinition1/versions/2020.09.12' under resource group 'IMAGEGALLERYRG' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound
ErrorMessage: The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/WVDImageGallery3/images/WVDBaseImageDefinition1/versions/2020.09.12' under resource group 'IMAGEGALLERYRG' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
ErrorTarget: 
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: Not Found
OperationID : c5ec1aec-9ec9-4287-ba80-8ad4d689945d
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

This is actually correct, but I want to write my code in such a way as if the Azure ARM resource doesn't exist and if I get the error code ResourceNotFound it should create the new resource. Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Something like this:

```
Write-Host "Checking the image version already exists or not..................."

if(Get-AzGalleryImageVersion -ResourceGroupName $rgname -GalleryName $galName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $imageDefinitionName -GalleryImageVersionName $versionName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Write-Host "The image version which has been requested in this pipeline task already exists, no action is taken, goodbye!!!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "Creating and replicating the new image, it may take hours depending on the size of the image and network speed"
    $ImageVersion=New-AzGalleryImageVersion -ResourceGroupName $rgname -GalleryName $galName -GalleryImageDefinitionName $imageDefinitionName -GalleryImageVersionName $versionName -Location $location -Source $sourceImageId -PublishingProfileEndOfLifeDate $endOfLifeDate -TargetRegion $targetRegions
    ############################## Publish new Image Gallery ####################### 
    Write-Host "The Gallery Image Version is ready please find below" -ForegroundColor "Green"
    $ImageVersion
}
```